# C++ создание службы для Windows, нужны ссылки на хороше руководство (специально для маленьких и тупых)

Tags: c++, windows, служба

Я тут задался целью написать на Си++ свою собственную службу с блэкджеком и... ну вы поняли. Я обычно глупые вопросы задаю одному широкоизвестному глупому роботу, но тут что-то у нас образовалась неожиданная пробуксовка, дело не двигается с мертвой точки. Код, который он предлагает, не активируется в Винде, там ошибка... Не помню точно номер, типа 1053 (не уверен), в общем, суть такая: "Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно", а что это за запрос такой, этот болван объяснить не может. Думаю, чем выводить его на чистую воду, лучше не полениться и почитать статейки. Если кто знает, пожалуйста, киданите ссылок! Можно и на английском.

Comment: Есть [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://www.nssm.cc/), который поднимает любой экзешник как службу. У нас на работе его используют.

Comment: Спасибо! Это прикольно, мне особенно нравится название - руку бы пожал этим ребятам, молодцы! Но у меня немного другая задача, мне надо чтобы все работало на любом компе без привлечения стороннего ПО. Грубо говоря, чтобы моя прога при необходимости могла поднимать его (сервис) сама без лишних танцев с бубнами.

Comment: У нас экзешник NSSM устанавливаетя рядом с нашим экзешником, и какими-то консольными командами настраивается (автоматически из нашего инсталлера). В принципе со стороны не особо незаметно, что служба через него сделана.

Comment: Ну, в общем, изучу, спасибо! )

Comment: Нашел примерчик на Гитхабе, это прям идеал ) https://github.com/sethlans01/Windows-Service А вообще, после опыта написания демонов для Linux это кажется какой-то жесткой трешатиной, уж слишком многабукав )

Answer (score 1):

Читайте официальную [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winsvc/) на сайте мелкомягких

Помимо собственно доков, там есть [пример сервиса](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/the-complete-service-sample)

Ошибка "служба не ответила своевременно", скорее всего связана с тем что вы не установили хэндлер управления сервисом через [RegisterServiceCtrlHandler()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-registerservicectrlhandlera)(или некорректно обрабатываете запросы ОС)